# How to set scope subtree in AuthenticationManagerBuilder in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I am connecting to an LDAP using AuthenticationManagerBuilder inside a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class in Spring. The configure method is the following:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(autoLDAP)
        .contextSource()
        .url(env.getProperty("ldap.address"))
        .managerDn(env.getProperty("ldap.manager"))
        .managerPassword(env.getProperty("ldap.manager.password"))
        .and().userDnPatterns(env.getProperty("ldap"));

}
```

autoLDAP is an LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.
And those properties are the following:

```
ldap.address=ldap://W.X.Y.Z:389/dc=whatever,dc=com
ldap.patterns=CN={0},OU=Users,OU=Company,OU=MyCity
ldap.manager=Manager
ldap.manager.password=123456789
```

If I keep things like that it works for users in "OU=MyCity", but I want to search for uses in "other cities" as well. So I want a search with properties like this that search on subtrees:

```
ldap.address=ldap://W.X.Y.Z:389/dc=whatever,dc=com
ldap.patterns=CN={0}
ldap.manager=Manager
ldap.manager.password=123456789
```

I've been searching a lot about this but I can't find where to set the scope to subtree using those classes.
Thanks for your help.